Vibration problem when rotating ImageView in UIButton - iOS
Comparison with the first function call
I created a UIButton with text and images that fetched the calendar.
And I'm rotating the imageView 90 degrees with the button action.
However, as you can see from the bottom of the gif, the image shakes and rotates when you first press the button.
When you press the button afterwards, it disappears. I wonder what the problem is.
Please help me with what I'm missing. A small problem is very disturbing to me.
Below are the codes that make up the button and the button action.
    private lazy var datePickingButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "chevron.backward"), for: .normal)
        button.imageView?.contentMode = .center
        button.imageView?.clipsToBounds = false
        button.setTitle("\(dateString)", for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "SFProDisplay-Bold", size: 20)
        button.tintColor = .mainTheme
        button.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft

        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(datePickingButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        let spacing: CGFloat = 6
        button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: spacing, bottom: 0, right: -spacing)
        button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: -spacing, bottom: 0, right: spacing)
        button.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: spacing + button.imageView!.frame.width, bottom: 0, right: spacing)
        return button
    }()

    @objc func datePickingButtonTapped() {
        let dateSelectVC = DateSelectVC()
        dateSelectVC.selectedDate = self.selectedDate
        dateSelectVC.delegate = self
        dateSelectVC.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
        if let popoverController = dateSelectVC.popoverPresentationController {
            popoverController.sourceView = self.datePickingButton
            popoverController.sourceRect = self.datePickingButton.bounds
            popoverController.permittedArrowDirections = [.up, .down]
            popoverController.delegate = self
        }
        dateSelectVC.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 400, height: 400)
        self.present(dateSelectVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

        // 이미지 회전 애니메이션
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
            self.datePickingButton.imageView?.transform = self.datePickingButton.imageView?.transform.rotated(by: .pi / 2) ?? CGAffineTransform.identity
        })
    }

